# Handling different json formats in Presto when extracting as string?

Tags: sql, json, presto

I am trying to extract a string from a JSON in presto. Here are the 2 options for how the extracted data can look before I cast to a string:

1. `JSON_EXTRACT(my_column, '$.my_column_extract')` = ["A::1","B::2","C::3","D::4"]
2. `JSON_EXTRACT(my_column, '$.my_column_extract')` = {"0":"A::1","1":"B::2","2":"C::3","3":"D::4,5"}

For both above options, the goal string format I want to achieve:
For 1) A::1, B::2, C::3, D::4
For 2) A::1, B::2, C::3, D::4,5

So I cast as `ARRAY(VARCHAR)` and then `ARRAY_JOIN` to get a string. This works for 1) but not for 2).

1. ARRAY_JOIN(
   CAST(
   JSON_EXTRACT(my_column, '$.my_column_extract') AS ARRAY(VARCHAR)
   ),
   ', '
   ) = A::1, B::2, C::3, D::4
2. The same functions result in an error due the format. Error notice
   (INVALID_CAST_ARGUMENT) Cannot cast to array(varchar). Expected a json array, but got {"0":"A::1","1":"B::2","2":"C::3","3":"D::4,5"}

How can I get 2) to result in the goal string format?

Comment: Can you update your question with sample JSON records for both cases and expected output as a whole?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your records are available only in those two formats then you can leverage `try_cast` function which returns `null` if the cast can't be performed and use `coalesce` two cast to the second format:

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset(my_column) AS (
 values ('{"my_column_extract":["A::1","B::2","C::3","D::4"]}'),
        ('{"my_column_extract":{"0":"A::1","1":"B::2","2":"C::3","3":"D::4,5"}}')
),

-- query parts
extracted as (
    select JSON_EXTRACT(my_column, '$.my_column_extract') extr
    from dataset)

SELECT coalesce(
        try_cast(extr as array(varchar)), -- try process array
        map_values(cast(extr as map(varchar, varchar)))) -- if not array - process json object as map and get map values
FROM extracted;
```

Output:

| _col0 |
| --- |
| [A::1, B::2, C::3, D::4] |
| [A::1, B::2, C::3, D::4,5] |

And then process resulting arrays as needed